# Referencing a nested field in mongodb model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I am using nodejs with mongoose to manage mongodb data base
I have two model schemas

the first one (CustomersMessages) document looks like this

```
{   "_id": ObjectId("643dbcca2329d2bf497977a2"),
    "name": "User",
    "messages": [{
        "message": "Hello, I am interested in this project",
        "refrenceName": "x123",
        "_id": ObjectId("643dbcca2329d2bf497977a5"),
        
    }],
    "__v": 0
}
```

and the second one (Users) document looks like this

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("6260267ce449a8c74cf77ef7"),
    "email": "admin@admin.com",
    "password": "####",
    "name": "admin",
    "unreadMessages": [
     {"_id":ObjectId("643dbcca2329d2bf497977a5")}                      
                       ]
 
    "__v": 0,
  
}
```

and the admin schema looks like this

```
const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    email: { type: String, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    unreadMessages: [
      {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "CustomerMessages",
      },
    ],
  },
);
```

I am trying to populate the admin schema with message , i am doing

```
User.find().populate('unreadMessages')
```

but what i get back is an empty array since i can not specify the messages field inside the "CustomerMessages" Schema.

Any advice how can i access it ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it with a aggregation:

```
db.user.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "customermessages",
      localField: "unreadMessages._id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "unreadMessages",
      
    },
    
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$unreadMessages",
    
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      email: {
        $first: "$email"
      },
      password: {
        $first: "$password"
      },
      name: {
        $first: "$name"
      },
      unreadMessages: {
        $push: "$unreadMessages"
      },
      
    },
    
  },
  
])
```

You can see it on [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/R57HC7tgH42)